# CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE qualcomm hexagon 682

Tags: hexagon-dsp

I have been trying to understand how to write code targeting the qualcomm hexagon 682. In order to understand how build a project I imitated the makefiles they had in the the calculator example. I have sucessfully built the project. Put the resulting lib in /vendor/lib/rfsa/adsp and the executable in data/local/. Once I try to execute my program, it gives an error that libsum.so was not found ( which is the library I built and had put in the /vendor/lib/rfsa/adsp  directory). Is there a missing step ?

Am testing on Open-Q 835 board with android 7

Comment: Can you share the details including the specific command that gives the error and the exact error it gives?